# Creating 1D zero array in Octave

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, octave

How can we create an array with `n` elements. `zeros` function can create only arrays of dimensions greater than or equal to 2? `zeros(4)`, `zeros([4])` and `zeros([4 4])` all create 2D zero matrix of dimensions 4x4.

I have a code in Python where I have used `numpy.zeros(n)`. I wish to do something similar in Octave.

Comment: Literally "zeros octave" in Google gives the [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/v4.0.1/Special-Utility-Matrices.html), which states *"If invoked with two or more scalar integer arguments, or a vector of integer values, return an array with the given dimensions.."*

Comment: @Wolfie it gives 2D result for single value for dimension too. That is, zeros(4) gives 2D matrix as well.

Comment: Yes, the important bit is ***with the given dimensions***, if you pass 1 then that dimension is 1! The line above that in the docs states *"If invoked with a single scalar integer argument, return a square NxN matrix."*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`zeros(n,1)` works well for me in Octave.

Answer (score 2):

A vector is a *row* vector in Octave. So if you want to create a vector of zeros, you need to use the command:

```
    b = zeros(1,n)
```

The command

```
    c = zeros(n,1)
```

will create a column vector of zeros.